# How can a attribute (which is a class) access the class to which it is an attribute?

Tags: class, attributes, raku

A confusing title, I know.  But the code should be clear:

```
class A {
    has $.foo = 1;
    # how can I access B::bar from here?
}

class B {
    has $.bar = 2;
    has A $.a;
    submethod TWEAK {
        $!a = A.new;
    }
}

my $b = B.new;
say $b;    # B.new(bar => 2, a => A.new(foo => 1))
say $b.a;  # A.new(foo => 1)
my $test := $b.a;
say $test; # A.new(foo => 1)
```

Given `$test`, how can I access B::bar (which is on the same "level" as $test)?

Comment: I don't understand your question, and I have to go to sleep, but insert a forward declaration `class B { ... }` (with the three dot `...` included) as the first line of code and then write `say B.new.bar` in the body of the `A` class.

Comment: I don't know why you have a `TWEAK` submethod. You should be able to do it in the declaration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Personally if I had to do this I'd state that `A` can have an attribute `parent` that fulfils a Role `HasBar` like so.

```
role HasBar {
    has $.bar = 2;
}

class A {
   has $.foo = 1;
   has HasBar $.parent;
}

class B does HasBar {
    has A $.a;
    submethod TWEAK {
        $!a = A.new( parent => self );
    }
}
```

Attributes generally don't (and shouldn't) know if they are contained in another object. So if you want to be able to do that you need to tell them the connection exists. I prefer using Roles to do this as then your `A` class could be an attribute in lots of different things as long as the container has a `bar` accessible.

Comment: Thank you - that is a very clear explanation.  I'll rework my code so that my Attributes won't need to know that they are contained in another object.  But I like the parent/role trick!  I'll play around with it until I fully grok it.  Thanks for you help!
-- Jim

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
class B { ... }            #need to decl B before you use it

class A { 
    has $.foo is rw = 1;   #foo is already =1
    has B $.b;
}                          #no TWEAK needed

class B { 
    has $.bar is rw = 2;
    has A $.a;
}

say my $a = A.new(b => B.new);
say my $b = B.new(a => A.new);
say my $a2 = A.new(b => $b);                
say my $b2 = B.new(a => $a2);

say $a2.b.bar;   #2  
say $b2.a.foo;   #1

$b2.a.b.a.foo = 42;         #added is rw trait to show this
say $b2;

#B.new(bar => 2, a => A.new(foo => 1, b => B.new(bar => 2, a => A.new(foo => 42, b => B))))
```

If you look at the output you will see that the $b2 is a nested recursion. Not sure if that is what you want! My bet is that @scimon s answer is a better one...

Comment: Oh, that's cheeky!  I'll add it to my toolkit.  Thanks!  -- Jim